# Postgres, execute a multiple query keeping a 1:1 ratio

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to run 3 queries at once. So on the first statement I get the number of times I have to run it for the next two statements. The problem is that the last command is executed  more times than needed. 
The query I've written is:

```
WITH rows_1 AS (
    SELECT t1.name, t1.value
    FROM table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN aux_table2 AS ps
    ON ps.id = t1.id AND ps.value='pepe'
    )
, rows_2 AS  (
    INSERT INTO table2 (value1, value2)
    SELECT 'value1', 'value2' FROM rows_1 as sr
    RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO table3
    (value1, value2, value3)
SELECT sr.value, st.id, sr.name,
FROM rows_1 AS sr, rows_2 AS st
;
```

The problem is that the first query gives the number of object we have (N), and the two following queries have to be done N times each, so the ratio of the two inserts is 1:1, and I am not able to achieve it, the last one is currently executed NxN times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite unclear how the tables line up.  The rows going into `rows_2` are all identical, except for default values invisible in this query.

That said, you can add a sequential number to each row set and use that for the `JOIN`:

```
WITH rows_1 AS (
    SELECT t1.name, t1.value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as seqnum
    FROM table1 t1 JOIN
        aux_table2 ps
        ON ps.id = t1.id AND ps.value='pepe'
    ),
    rows_2 AS  (
      INSERT INTO table2 (value1, value2)
          SELECT 'value1', 'value2'
          FROM rows_1 sr
          RETURNING id
    )
INSERT INTO table3 (value1, value2, value3)
    SELECT sr.value, st.id, sr.name,
    FROM rows_1 sr JOIN
         (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as seqnum
          FROM rows_2 st
         ) st
         ON st.seqnum = sr.seqnum;
```

Comment: I only needed to add one small modification bu it worked fine! Thanks